# How could I augment object in Java with properties of another object?

Tags: java, javabeans

I would like to copy the properties of an object to another, only if they are not null and exist in the target object. 
I know `BeanUtils.copyProperties` but it doesn't exactly suit the need.

What totally suit is the [jquery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function. Is there an equivalent in the Java libraries/frameworks ?
(or else I'll write my own...)

For example, the destination object is User, and the origin is UserSettings :

```
User                           UserSettings                     User
fisrtName="Rick"               firstName=null                  fisrtName="Rick"  
lastName="Dangerous"  extends  lastName="newLastName"  gives   lastName="newLastName"
nickName="RD"                                                  nickName="RD"
```

---

**EDIT**

Finally I wrote my own method, if anyone is interested see https://gist.github.com/1602045

Comment: what about `.clone()` method? you should be able to call `obj.clone()` and it will return cloned object

Comment: No because I have a target object with values I want to keep if the first object values are null.

Comment: To be honest this sounds like that your whole basic design of your program seems to be "off". Java and JavaScript are conceptually two completely different languages and an idea like jQuery's `extend` simply doesn't (or better "shouldn't") apply to Java.  Can you give an example of the code and the classes you are using? And explain why you think yo need ´extend`.

Comment: Are those the examples objects (classes)? Why? Why not a `Map`?

Comment: They are objects, because UserSettings is an object populated by a html form jsonified, and User is a JPA entity.

Comment: If you can't clone, then you probably will need to use reflections API. But it will turn out to be damn overcomplexified.

Comment: that's what I'm doing right now...

Comment: @tbruyelle you asked this 3 years ago, did you find different way. Is there any function for Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

Your code would still benefit from the beanutils

```
PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty()
```

and

```
PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty()
```

methods

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`BeanUtilsBean.copyProperties(o1, o2)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: As I said it doesn't suit because null properties from origin object overrides ones of destination object. Null properties in origin object need to be skipped